# How can I get the count of JSON array in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure data factory to retrieve data and copy into a database... the Source looks like this:

```
{
    "GroupIds": [
        "4ee1a-0856-4618-4c3c77302b",
        "21259-0ce1-4a30-2a499965d9",
        "b2209-4dda-4e2f-029384e4ad",
        "63ac6-fcbc-8f7e-36fdc5e4f9",
        "821c9-aa73-4a94-3fc0bd2338"
    ],
    "Id": "w5a19-a493-bfd4-0a0c8djc05",
    "Name": "Test Item",
    "Description": "test item description",
    "Notes": null,
    "ExternalId": null,
    "ExpiryDate": null,
    "ActiveStatus": 0,
    "TagIds": [
        "784083-4c77-b8fb-0135046c",
        "86de96-44c1-a497-0a308607",
        "7565aa-437f-af36-8f9306c9",
        "d5d841-1762-8c14-d8420da2",
        "bac054-2b6e-a19b-ef5b0b0c"
    ],
    "ResourceIds": []
}
```

In my ADF pipeline, I am trying to get the count of GroupIds and store that in a database column (along with the associated Id from the JSON above).

Is there some kind of syntax I can use to tell ADF that I just want the count of GroupIds or is this going to require some kind of recursive loop activity?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `length` function in Azure Data Factory (ADF) to check the length of json arrays:

```
length(json(variables('varSource')).GroupIds)
```

If you are loading the data to a SQL database then you could use `OPENJSON`, a simple example:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
    "GroupIds": [
        "4ee1a-0856-4618-4c3c77302b",
        "21259-0ce1-4a30-2a499965d9",
        "b2209-4dda-4e2f-029384e4ad",
        "63ac6-fcbc-8f7e-36fdc5e4f9",
        "821c9-aa73-4a94-3fc0bd2338"
    ],
    "Id": "w5a19-a493-bfd4-0a0c8djc05",
    "Name": "Test Item",
    "Description": "test item description",
    "Notes": null,
    "ExternalId": null,
    "ExpiryDate": null,
    "ActiveStatus": 0,
    "TagIds": [
        "784083-4c77-b8fb-0135046c",
        "86de96-44c1-a497-0a308607",
        "7565aa-437f-af36-8f9306c9",
        "d5d841-1762-8c14-d8420da2",
        "bac054-2b6e-a19b-ef5b0b0c"
    ],
    "ResourceIds": []
}'

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON( @json, '$.GroupIds' )

SELECT COUNT(*) countOfGroupIds
FROM OPENJSON( @json, '$.GroupIds' );
```

My results:

[image: results]

If your data is stored in a table the code is similar.  Make sense?

Another funky way to approach it if you really need the count in-line, is to convert the JSON to XML using the built-in functions and then run some XPath on it.  It's not as complicated as it sounds and would allow you to get the result inside the pipeline.

The Data Factory [XML function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#xml) converts JSON to XML, but that JSON must have a single root property.  We can fix up the json with `concat` and a single line of code.  In this example I'm using a Set Variable activity, where `varSource` is your original JSON:

```
@concat('{"root":', variables('varSource'), '}')
```

Next, we can just apply the XPath with another simple expression:

```
@string(xpath(xml(json(variables('varIntermed1'))), 'count(/root/GroupIds)'))
```

My results:

[image]

Easy huh.  It's a shame there isn't more built-in support for JPath unless I'm missing something, although you can use limited JPath in the Copy activity.

Comment: Just out of interest, was it the database or XPath technique you ended up using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Data flow` activity in the Azure data factory pipeline to get the **count**.

**Step1**:

- Connect the `Source` to JSON dataset, and in Source options under **JSON settings**, select **single document**.
- In the source preview, you can see there are 5 GroupIDs per ID.

[image]

**Step2**:

- Use [flatten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten) transformation to deformalize the values into rows for GroupIDs.
- Select GroupIDs array in Unroll by and Unroll root.

[image]

[image]

**Step3**:

- Use [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-aggregate) transformation, to get the count of GroupIDs group by ID.
- Under **Group by**: Select a column from the drop-down for your aggregation.

[image]

- Under **Aggregate**: You can build the expression to get the count of the column (GroupIDs).

[image]

Aggregate Data preview:

[image]

**Step4**:  Connect the output to `Sink` transformation to load the final output to database.

[image]